# to change the color of areas of my pie chart HIGHCHART

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I want to change the color of areas of my pie chart Highcharts according to my preferences.

How I can do it ?

Comment: What have you done so far? Could you give more specific info about your issue? Did you read Highcharts documentation and their API? http://www.highcharts.com/docs http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to go about this.

**First**, you can use the `Highcharts.setOptions()` function to define your own color choices. Your chart will pick up these colors in the order you specify, and will repeat them when it reaches the end of the list.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: [
        '#FF0000', /* red */
        '#00FF00', /* green */
        '#0000FF', /* blue */
    ],
});
```

So, in this example, your pie wedges would be red, green, blue, red, green, etc., in that order.

You'll want to define your `Highcharts.setOptions()` colors before you draw your chart.

**Second**, you can define the specific colors of your pie wedges directly in the chart attributes. For each data point in your pie chart's series, you can set the color as follows:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Test',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Red slice',
        y: 70,
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        name: 'Green slice',
        y: 20,
        color: 'green'
    }, {
        name: 'Blue slice',
        y: 10,
        color: 'blue'
    }]
}]
```

Here's a fiddle with the second example: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/v917r91L/

I hope this is helpful!